# How can I get FTP/Remote Editing on Sublime Text on Windows 7 (open source)?

Tags: windows-7, ftp, ide

I really dig Sublime Text (replacing Ultra Edit for me), but not being able to edit files remotely kills my workflow.

I've tried all kinds of things like syncing over ssh, rsync, etc., but these all turned out to be a nightmare (overwriting the wrong files, including svn files when it shouldn't, etc.)

I used to use Eclipse, and Aptana Studio, but the limitations around Syntax highlighting are deal breakers for me.

It's frustrating because Ultra Edit's FTP is rather dodgy at times, so a real solution would be nice!

Can anyone recommend a usable workflow tool chain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To edit files over SFTP, first install [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control). Then, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `Package Control: Install Package`. Press Enter, type `SFTP`, and press Enter again. This installs the SFTP package.

To control this package, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, type `SFTP:`, and then select the command you want to run.

NOTE: This isn't an open source package, but rather works much the same as Sublime Text itself: the free version is technically a trial, but it is neither time- nor feature-limited, and all it does is pop up a window every 15 or so saves.

Comment: Thanks for the update. A lot of IDE's come with SFTP/FTP support already, its disappointing that Sublime Text does not. I don't feel OK about paying for a feature that should be part of the standard feature set, especially after paying for Sublime Text. Oh well! I may go back to UltraEdit afterall.

Comment: I feel your pain. The cool kids tell me I should use Sublime but it's missing so many features that UltraEdit has 'out the box' and has so many difficult to use features (block editing, omfg!) that it's difficult to continue to believe that the cool kids really are correct in this instance.